# How to remove extra hyphens from string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a string in which spaces are replaced by `hyphen i.e '-'` if there multiple hyphens then I want to remove all but one from the string. Only hyphens must be removed; not numbers that are consecutive.

> Eg: --11- must be -11- and not -1-
>    Eg: --12-   o/p: -12-
>    Eg: -12--  o/p: -12-

using Linq or a string function in C#.

I have tried it using `str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);`, but it only removes one character.

Comment: I am not sure I understood you correctly. You provided an example input, could you also provide an example output?

Comment: its already their inline..! plz check..!

Comment: Is it only `-` or any character?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: its only - & @DGibbs i have tried it using str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1); it remove one character..!

Comment: You mention `next similar consecutive character` in the title and `if there is similar character one after other then i want to remove the next occurrence from string if exists.`. Is this **just for hyphens** or does this apply to any character, e.g. `aa12a` would become `a12a`

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE You should include this relevant information in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to collapse multiple consecutive `-` characters into one, you could easily do this using regex:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\-+", "-");
```

Comment: @GrantThomas: I assumed there could be any number of consecutive `-` characters; in which case, `string.Replace` won't work.

Comment: Thank You All for just voting down..even after corrections! :(

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE: I assume you meant to post that under your original question?

Comment: hello @Douglas, i have modified my post is it ok now? sorry for inconvinience..! and thanks for helping me..!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
string sample = "--12";
string Reqdoutput =  sample.Replace("--", "-");
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of the `Replace`.

Comment: It doesn't work if there are more than 2 successive similar characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace just the hyphen, you can do one of the things given in the other answers. For removing all double characters, you can do this:

```
        String input = "------hello-----";
        int i = 1;
        while (i < input.Length)
        {
            if (input[i] == input[i - 1])
            {
                input = input.Remove(i, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(input); // Will give "-helo-"
```

Comment: +1, but I'd still use regex for this.

Comment: @Douglas When in doubt, I prefer not to use regex, unless I am pretty confident that every programmer involved in the software I am involved in will be as proficient in regex as I am. If they're not, I have produced code which they cannot maintain. Unless, of course, the problem is complex enough so that a non-regex solution itself would be unnecessarily complex. But for simple problems, like this one, I prefer standard code.

Comment: Fair enough, but when you're doing text processing, it's typically worthwhile for all involved developers to incur the learning curve of regex. A few characters of regex is more maintainable than several lines of logic. Furthermore, your code is very inefficient, since you're creating a new string for each removed character.

Comment: @Douglas Typically, text processing is only a small part of a much larger system, so it is difficult to even define "all involved developers." Also, I would maintain that all code is efficient enough until it proves to be too inefficient in this scenario. See premature optimization. But we are getting quite code-philosophical now, let's just agree to disagree :-)

Comment: Agree (or disagreed?) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do :

```
yourString = yourString.Replace("--", "-");
```

Or did I understand the problem wrong ?